# Use admin-user in your model

Tags: python, django

I just started fiddling with Django, and I try now to use the users that are available in the admin page in a model.

This is my model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
      started_at = models.DateTimeField()

class Player(models.Model):
      game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
      user = models.ForeignKey(models.User)
```

but this doesn't work: `python manage.py makemigrations` returns:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'User'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `User` model is available from `django.contrib.auth.models`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Game(models.Model):
      started_at = models.DateTimeField()


class Player(models.Model):
      game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User) # models.User doesn't exist
```